# How to decrease load time of join query in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am using $wpdb Object to display some data in WordPress post loop.

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```

The code I want to put in that loop is:

```
<h3><font color="#F60"><?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `link` gl, `social` ls WHERE `sd`= 12 AND gl.lik = '$lisd' AND gl.lik_id = ls.lik_id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1" )); 
if (!$result) {
    echo "0";
}
else{
     foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $shares=$row->social_counts;                                            
        echo abbNumber($shares);
    }
}

?>  </font> <font color="#666">SHARES</font></h3>
```

Is there any way to run that query in that loop using ajax or can I run that query after page load? I want to decrease the load time of that query?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please try with bellow query.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `link` gl
INNER JOIN 
    `social` ls ON gl.lik_id = ls.lik_id
WHERE
    `sd` = 12
    AND gl.lik = '$lisd'
ORDER BY
    date DESC
```

LIMIT 1

Also add indexing on lik_id and lik_id

Comment: its showing me error of syntax, also what is indexing?

Comment: Check i have updated query there is one extra space i have added by mistake

Comment: For create index please execute bellow query on phpmyadmin..`CREATE INDEX lik_id_index ON social (lik_id) USING BTREE;` you need to execute this query only one time

Comment: Ok now its working and it decreases 0.1 sec of load time. If I removed all these queries then it decrease load time to 1 sec. Can I make it more smoother by any other way, like Ajax or JavaScript or anything else

Comment: Have you added indexing ?